# Laravel eloquent error with "hasmany" relationship

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent, has-many

I have this annoying problem when trying to execute a hasMany method:

I have a **Task model**, of which I want to retrieve all the states

```
class Task extends Eloquent {
protected $guarded = array();

public static $rules = array();


public function states(){
    return $this->hasMany('TaskState','task_id');
}
```

...from this **TaskState model** (db has  columns: task_id, user_id, status)

```
class TaskState extends Eloquent {
public $table= "taskstates";
protected $guarded = array();

public static $rules = array();


public function task(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Task','task_id');
}
```

However when I try to execute this,

```
$task = Task::find($id);
    return $task->states;
```

it keeps giving this error:

```
Call to undefined method TaskState::newQuery()
```

I'm stuck on this for like two days. Would anyone know what the problem might be here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like it may be a namespace issue - if the `TaskState` class truly extends `Eloquent`, then it should have a `newQuery()` method. However, have you tried to manually call that method?

Comment: The inverse of the `hasMany()` function is `belongsTo()`.  So on your `task()` function try returning `return $this->belongsTo('Task', 'task_id')`;.  `belongsToMany()` is usually used for pivot tables.

Comment: I've changed it to belongsTo(), but the same error remains :s thanks anyway for mentioning!

Comment: @alexrussell What do you exactly mean with manually calling? I'm a bit new to Laravel

Comment: @vrijdrogenaam I mean have you tried (in a controller or `artisan tinker` simply doing `var_dump(TaskState::newQuery());` to see whether the error message is telling the truth about the method not existing, or if it's some other underlying problem (maybe it can't find the class and manages to not error about that).

Comment: @alexrussell I've tried this, but i keep getting the same error "Call to undefined method TaskState::newQuery()".

Comment: Then I think you need to ensure that the class definitely 100% extends the `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class. Maybe you have some weird alias on `Eloquent` that means it's not **the** Eloquent class that Laravel expects (maybe some package that hijacks the `\Eloquent` class alias but doesn't extend \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model like it should?)

Comment: If it helps anyone I had this error because I had `class MyClass extends BaseController`. `BaseController` should be `Eloquent`. It took me a minute to realize my mistake with this vague message.

Answer (score 0):

If there is one-to-many relationship between models, then you should use 'belongsTo' in TaskState instead of 'belongsToMany;

Comment: I've already tried changing this, but in vain: the error remains. Thanks anyway :)